# Create, Read and Write to dynamic array in separate tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

I want to create a grid of squares(m width x n height) with their coordinates printed in them. And a second picture of all the rows concatenated in tikz picture. Can I do this in two separate tikz images?

```tex
% tikzpicture 1
% Each of this is in a box
(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) ... (0, m) 
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) ... (1, m) 
(2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2) ... (2, m) 
(3, 0) (3, 1) (3, 2) ... (3, m) 
...
(n, 0) (n, 1) (n, 2) ... (n, m)
```

```tex
% tikzpicture 2
% Each of this is in a box, so adjecent boxes
(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2).... (0, m) (1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, m) ... (2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, m) ... (3, 0) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, m) ... (n, 0) (n, 1) (n, 2) ...(n, m)
```

But if the dimensions (mxn) change, I want it to dynamically change as well. When I compute the coordinates in sequence with two two foreach loops and the other prints the precomputed array in order.

This is what I have so far for the first loop:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit} % for small squares in src/2D_array_indexing
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\def\gridSize{10mm}
\def\SquareDim{4mm}
\def\Width{4}
\def\Height{3}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\gridSize, y=-\gridSize]
        \newcommand\Square[1]{+(-#1,-#1) rectangle +(#1,#1)}
        %%%%%% \draw [very thin, lightgray] (0,0) grid (6,4); % Temporary grid
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\Width}
        \foreach \y in {0,...,\Height}
            {
                \draw (\x,\y) \Square{\SquareDim};
                \node[anchor=center, minimum size=1cm] at (\x,\y) {\scriptsize{(\x, \y)}};
                 % Store the values in sequence in an array here for printing it out later.
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is what I have so far, from the 1st loop:

[image: What I have so far...]

I've tried searching for answers for storing and printing the strings in arrays, but none seem to work for me.

### Edit

Added a complete example, and no, I do not have a specific reason to create arrays within the tikzpicture, it can be outside or under any scope which would be valid in both tikz pictures.(Thanks! @cfr ).

PS: I do not know if all the packages mentioned are supposed to be included, they have accumulated as I was trying out answers from various other StackOverflow answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please provide a complete example. How are `\Width` and `\Height` defined? From what you've shown, it would probably make more sense to define the array first outside any `tikzpicture` and then use it in the `tikzpicture`s. Is there some reason you want to create the array inside a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an example of this type in https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/10/04/latex3-tutorial.html

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={
    minimum height=0.8cm,
    minimum width=0.8cm,
    draw,
    anchor=north west,
    font=\scriptsize
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_x_int
\int_new:N \l_libx_int
\int_new:N \l_y_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\printgrid}{ m m }
{
  % #1 the number of row (x)
  % #2 the number of column (y)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\int_step_inline:nn {#1} 
  {
    \int_step_inline:nn {#2} {
      \int_set:Nn \l_x_int{ \int_eval:n { ####1 } - 1 }
      \int_set:Nn \l_y_int { \int_eval:n { ##1 } - 1 }
      \node[mynode] at (\int_eval:n { \l_x_int }, -\int_eval:n { \l_y_int }) {(\int_eval:n { \l_x_int },\int_eval:n { \l_y_int })};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printline}{ m m }
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } 
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn {#2} {
          \int_set:Nn \l_x_int{ \int_eval:n { ####1 } - 1 + ( ##1 - 1 ) * #2}
          \int_set:Nn \l_libx_int{ \int_eval:n { ####1 } - 1 }
          \int_set:Nn \l_y_int { \int_eval:n { ##1 } - 1 }
          \node[mynode] at (\int_eval:n { \l_x_int }, 0 ) {(\int_eval:n { \l_libx_int },\int_eval:n { \l_y_int })};
        }
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
In grid:

\printgrid{2}{3}

And in line:

\printline{2}{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]